# Properties of closure on a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,t)$ be a topological space with $M,N \subseteq X$

I though that if $M\cap N\neq \varnothing  $ the it would be true that $CL(M)\cap CL(N)\subseteq CL(M\cap N)$ clearly this doesn't work. I figure it later.
But I did try to prove it, and now I want to understand where the mistake on my proof was. My proof went like this.

Let $M\cap N\neq \varnothing  $ and take $a \in CL(M)\cap CL(N) $
that means that for every open set $U$ such that $a \in U$ we have $U \cap M \neq \varnothing$
similarly, we have that for every open set $V$ that $a \in V$ we have $V \cap N \neq \varnothing$
I now just took the union of those 2 and said $M\cap U \cup V\cap N\neq \varnothing$ and consider $U \cup V=W$ and I said $(M\cap N)\cap W\neq \varnothing$ so $CL(M)\cap CL(N)\subseteq CL(M\cap N)$

My mistake was that I said that $(M\cap N)\cap W\neq \varnothing \equiv  CL(M\cap N)$ and that is wrong because I didn't show that for every open $W$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to start with an *arbitrary* neighbourhood of $a$ and show it intersects $M \cap N$. You didn't do that. You know the neighbourhood intersects $M$ and $N$ as well, but you're not guaranteed any point in $M \cap N$ in that neighbourhood.

E.g. If $M$ equals the set of rationals in $\Bbb R$ and $N$ the set of all irrationals plus $\{0\}$, then $M \cap N = \{0\}$ which equals its own closure while the closure of both $M$ and $N$ are $\Bbb R$ and we have $\Bbb R$ on the left hand side.